# How do you fix a neural network giving the same output for different inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make an object detection neural network with keras using YOLOv1, and as of right now, the network is returning very similar outputs for very different inputs. I've tried to change the shape of the input from 416x416 to 100x100, I've tried decreasing the batch size from 32 to 4, and I've tried training it for a long amount of time (hundreds of epochs). Nothing's fixed the error, though. Any ideas?

The code for the neural network is [here](https://hastebin.com/quporinuxi.py).

And here's a [picture](https://image.prntscr.com/image/41zssh5tR4illZ9WFRv7NQ.png) of it.

Comment: nfi about this process but this looks like your passing a function that wants a parameter without one. ```parsed_image_dataset = raw_image_dataset.map(_parse_image_function)``` maybe should be ```parsed_image_dataset = raw_image_dataset.map(_parse_image_function(MISSING_STUFF))```  And should 'proto' be 'photo' ?

Comment: @Ross Williams, Is your issue resolved? Else, the link corresponding to the code for the Neural Network is blank. Can you please link it properly so that we can try to help you. Thanks!